# Organization Chart Double Color in 1 Box

Tags: highcharts, colors, project-organization

my issue is that I need to style 1 Box (Box=Task Box, background is stylebar with Color:) with 2 Colors.
So for example a task is done 20%, the normal box is yellow. But 20% should be a darker yellow to indicate that the task is 20% complete. Is there any possible way to do this very smoothly.
Thanks in advance
Juli.w
(And Im sry for my bad english, I’m German :))

Comment: Please, share a code sample and have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the color as a `Highcharts.GradientColorObject` to achieve the wanted result:

```
    nodes: [..., {
            ...,
            color: {
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    x2: 1,
                    y1: 0,
                    y2: 0
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#fffdaa'], // start
                    [0.25, '#fffdaa'], 
                    [0.25, '#878300'], 
                    [1, '#878300'] // end
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r6qxgLtm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.GradientColorObject